# Proper way to read entries in FileSystemEntry

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom

Currently I am using this code to read the entries in a `FileSystemEntry` object:

```js
  function readEntries(entry: FileSystemEntry): Promise<FileSystemEntry[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var reader: FileSystemDirectoryReader = entry.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(function (entries) {
        resolve(entries);
      });
    });
  }
```

However, TypeScript detects all these "bugs" (even though it works perfectly):

[image]

And Mozilla Developer Network claims: `Experimental. Expect behavior to change in the future.` [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryEntry/createReader)

How can an API be experimental and already deprecated at the same time and what should be the alternative?

Comment: The point of both messages is, don't expect it to work. As always, the alternative in TypeScript is to define your own type that has the functionality you desire.

Comment: What would be the point of TypeScript when I have to rewrite all API types (that could be unsupported in some niche browsers) myself to make it error-free?